# Bisection-Regula falsi-Bolzano

Tags: bisection

I want to ask about these theorems in **Matlab**, to confirm the requirement that **x1, x2 where f(x1) * f(x2) < 0** is there any way to find **x1, x2** if i have the function eg. $$f(x) = \tan(x)\frac{(e^{2x} - 1)}{(e^{2x} + 1)} + 1$$ by code.
Thanks

Comment: There is an infinite number of solutions. Look at what happens between $x=\frac \pi 2+\epsilon$ and $x=\frac{3 \pi} 2-\epsilon$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i took x1=0 and x2=2